# How to get the list of blocks for the current page?

Tags: 8, blocks

I'm trying to get the list of all blocks for a certain page, but I can't figure how to do that.

How do I get the list of all the blocks that are rendered for a page, independently from the region where they are put?

Answer (score 3):

To get all blocks in an array by region, you can do as follow

```
// Get the current theme used
$theme = \Drupal::theme()->getActiveTheme()->getName();

// And pass the theme name to get all the regions
$regions = system_region_list($theme, $show = REGIONS_ALL);

// This will give you all the regions in array format
$regions =  json_decode(json_encode(system_region_list(\Drupal::config('system.theme')->get('default'),$show = REGIONS_ALL)),true);

// Loop over each regions
foreach ($regions as $key => $region) {
  // Get the blocks in particular region
  $blocks[$key] = \Drupal::entityManager()
    ->getStorage('block')
    ->loadByProperties([
      'theme' =>  \Drupal::config('system.theme')->get('default'),
      'region'=> $key,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: how to get blocks according to current page in drupal 8?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more concise and accomplishes the same thing:

```
\Drupal::service('block.repository')->getVisibleBlocksPerRegion()
```